# Collect emails on Wordpress Checkout Page(for Mailchimp Audience)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, mailchimp

I have a shipping form with the NEXT button, which leads after the click on it to billing form with payment methods. And I want to collect emails of potential customers in my audience in Mailchimp, even if the customer didn't continue buying, just filled shipping, press NEXT, and then, for example, left the page.  But the email which he entered earlier on the shipping form already collected and added to my audience in Mailchimp.
[image]
Is it possible?

I found in the documentation of WooCommerce + Mailchimp, that need to add-in Audience settings in WordPress Mailchimp: *change the location of the opt-in:* **woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form**

which means hook, as I understand:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', $checkout ); ?>
```

but, unfortunately, I still can't see any new subscribers in my Mailchimp Audience.

I'm a newbie in Mailchimp, so maybe I do something wrong?